# What's the usage of ./lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++.a

Tags: c++, c, stl

All I have some questions as bellow:

1. Is `STL` header only library? Just like BOOST?
2. If `STL` is NOT header only, where is `STL`'s `cpp` files?
3. If `STL` is header only, why do we need `./lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++.a`?

Thank you

Comment: [3] `libstdc++.so.<version>` is dynamic library which get statically linked to executable when STL is used. For static linking `libstdc++.a` is required.

Comment: Question 0: why are you talking about "STL" ? I think you mean Standard Library. And no, the Standard Library doesn't just need .cpp files, it needs direct compiler support.

Comment: Poking around https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/tree/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B11 , you will find it is not header only.

Answer (score 2):

1. Libstdc++ is an implementation of the C++ standard library (not just "the STL").  It is NOT header-only.  (Neither are many parts of boost, for that matter).

As @sameerkn said, the non-header-only parts come in two flavors, a dylib (usually named something like `libstdc++.so.<version>`), and a file for static linking (usually named `libstdc++.a`). Most people use the dylib version.

2. The cpp files are used to build the libraries I described above. They're not installed on most systems, because most people don't rebuild their standard libraries - they just include the headers and link with the objects (either statically or dynamically).
3. See above - the library is not header only.